# How could cherry-pick other merge path?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, cherry-pick

I have this structure:

```
   B - C - D <- feature
  /         \  
 A-----------E <- master  
 ^ mytag
```

B, C and D commits are feature branch path. A is a common base. This feature is merged back into master as E commit. I have tagged (automatically) commit A.

I would like automatically without user intervention (from script), no matter how many commits are there in the feature branch to cherry pick "mytag" to "master" as A, E (in this case) in another branch.

Now if I do:

```
git checkout other    
git cherry-pick mytag..master
```

it will pick A, B, C, D and E commits. I would like it to pick commits only from master branch, i.e. A and E. 
Note: I don't want to merge into E in the opposide way. I want it feature into the master. And A to E is not sure that is branching at all. It could be A --- E. Just I need something like ".." operator, but to use other branch'es way.

Thanks for the help in advance!

In addition:
The third branch were I should cherry-pick, should look like that after:

```
F - G - H - A - E <- other
```

i.e. A and E will be cherry-picked in "other" branch.

Comment: Not very clear what the goal is. Can you provide a diagram of how the DAG should look like after the operation is done?

Comment: It should look like:
F - G - H - A - E <- other
i.e. A and E will be cherry-picked in "other" branch.

Comment: If you update your answer with that, we can see your beautiful ASCII Art better :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
call git cherry-pick -m 1 --first-parent mytag..master
if %errorlevel% == 128 then call git cherry-pick --first-parent mytag..master
```

**--first-parent** is undocumented option of **cherry-pick**. I saw it in **log** command and it is working for former, too. It is doing exactly what I need. To traverse first parent, not branch'es one as is by default.

```
git log --first-parent mytag..master
```

is returning only **A** and **E** commits.
**-m 1** option is used only for merge commits and fail for non-merge commits and vice verse. So I try with and if it fail - without.